# "cannot implicitly convert .." when using LINQ Where

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a query in a c# program that gets all items out of a database where a particular id in that item is contained in a list I have. I also need to join on a few tables..

What I have is:

```
var data = from a in db.Apples.Where(a => myApples.contains(a.type))
           from b in db.Banans where b.Id = a.bananaPair.Id
           from c in db.Coconuts where c.Id = c.coconutPair.Id
           select new {
               apple = a,
               bananaName = b.name,
               coconutName = c.name,
           });
```

I get an error on "where b.Id = a.bananaPair.Id" that "cannot implicitly convert int to bool". I think I am mixing types.. the first where is a comparison, and the others is a join condition. How can I do both in the query? I need pieces of information from all 3 tables in my select object.

Thanks

Comment: == is equality = is assignment

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
var data = from a in db.Apples.Where(a => myApples.contains(a.type))
       from b in db.Banans where b.Id == a.bananaPair.Id
       from c in db.Coconuts where c.Id == c.coconutPair.Id
       select new {
           apple = a,
           bananaName = b.name,
           coconutName = c.name,
       });
```

You had `b.Id = a.bananaPair.Id`. That assigns `a.bananaPair.Id` to `b.Id`. The reason your error was calling this assignment an `int` is because assignments return the value assigned. You want `b.Id == a.bananaPair.Id`, which tests whether they're equal.

As commenter @misterManager suggests, you could also use `join` here. Let me know if this doesn't work, though, it's been so long since I've used query syntax.

```
var data = from a in db.Apples.Where(a => myApples.contains(a.type))
       join b in db.Bananas on a.bananaPair.Id equals b.Id
       join c in db.Coconuts on c.coconutPair.Id equals c.Id
       select new {
           apple = a,
           bananaName = b.name,
           coconutName = c.name,
       });
```

By the way, I couldn't help but notice your `c` line: `from c in db.Coconuts where c.Id == c.coconutPair.Id`, should that be `a.coconutPair.Id`?

Comment: its also worth mentioning that you can use join keyword as well.... ie: join b in db.Bananas on a.bananaPair.Id equals b.Id.... additionally let b = a.Bananas if the db has proper integrity and allows such a navigation option

Comment: Oh my goodness are you kidding me haha. That is embarrassing! How come with SQL in server management studio or other times double equals isn't necessary? Either way - big thank you!

Comment: @jcam77 difference between sql and c# as languages. Your C# gets converted INTO sql which is what makes EF and other such frameworks so powerful. They don't execute C# necessarily... they actually transform your C# into SQL which is executed by the server and returned to you in a nice pretty object :) The sql that is output by your C# would NOT have the ==